# Use class templates inside another class template

Tags: c++, templates

Let's say I have some classes using templates like the following in some file(s) :

```cpp
    // PointerTemplates.hpp    

    template <class T>
    class Smart_Ptr_A
    {
      // [...]
    };

    template <class T>
    class Smart_Ptr_B
    {
      // [...]
    };
```

I would like to create another templated class that can use any of the previous classes.
Something like :

```cpp
    // ClassFoo.hpp

    class ClassBar;

    template<class PtrType>
    class ClassFoo
    {
      // [...]
      PtrType<ClassBar> m_pBar;
    };
```

How could I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use a [`template template` parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_arguments).

```
template <template<class> class PtrType>
class ClassFoo
{
  // [...]
  PtrType<ClassBar> m_pBar;
};
```